# Is it possible to create a template for Checklist in Trello?

Tags: trello

Basically, we are repeating the same task. I would like to know if there are templates for checklist. This way, I don't have to retype it each time I assign it to someone.

Answer (score 6):

There is currently a feature request card called *Templates for boards, lists, cards, and checklists* on the [Trello Development board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c).

The note on it says:

> We're still looking at how we want to implement this, but until we do, Phillip Epstein has created a Chrome Extension that does many of the things that people want.
>
> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/igdohpdnohikeonpipombhdepnmbigkl?hl=en-US&gl=US
>
> Old card for checklists https://trello.com/card/board/make-checklists-re-usable/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e1e0ab1802ec6e81c0ee19c

So the answer is no, checklist templates do not currently exist.

Comment: Nowadays, the answer is yes, checklist templates currently (since 2013) do exist. See http://help.trello.com/article/800-creating-templates-for-cards-lists-and-boards that reads _Create a card "Presentation Template" that contains checklists for all the things you need to do to prepare for a presentation. When you have to give the presentation again, just copy the card._
So, the 'template' for the checklist is contained on a card. Copying the card will create a new card plus checklist according the original checklist.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, is is possible. The [Trello help page on copying](http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/980926-copying-cards-boards-or-lists) mentions how to do that.

For more background information, there is an [earlier help page in Trello on templates](http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/981011-creating-templates-for-cards-lists-and-boards), and the [original Trello card for this feature](https://trello.com/card/copy-boards-cards-and-checklists/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/961).

Comment: Try to style your answer a bit.

Comment: Done. Although my restyled answer will not replace the (outdated) accepted answer. If it was you, you might remove your downvote.